# Difference between a controller (e.g PD) and a compensator(e.g Lead)?

Tags: control-theory

Really.What is it?Can't find anything anywhere related to it...Please don't give fancy examples.Just tell me the difference

Comment: What is a (e.g Lead) compensator, what is it used for, where did you see it mentioned?

Comment: I wouldn't be too concerned with semantics. 'Compensator' tends to be used for a sub-system that aims to improve one measurable aspect of a system, eg the phase margin. 'Controller' tends to be used more generically, and may seek to adjust a number of design criteria, eg steady state gain and overshoot.

Answer (score 5):

In simply words:

**Regulator (controller)** is a device that controls the object in closed loop on the basis of difference (error of regulation) between measurements of object's output and external steering signal, regulator tries to reduce error to zero.

**Compensator** only change object characteristics (transfer function), e.g. phase of output signal. Compensators are used in connection with regulators, in feedback loop (change characteristics of object's output signal) or in steering path (change steering signal from controller to object).

More here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Controllers_and_Compensators